# How to write a simple functional component that return a array list using map method

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to loop through a simple array inside a functional component so it returns list of names inside the array. The error I get is `Person(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

```
const Person = () => {

  var persons = ["John", "Ron"];

  persons.map(p => {
    return  (
      <div> 
         <ul> 
            <li> I am {p} </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    ) 
  })
}
```

Comment: you're not returning anything from the component, but only inside the map iteration

Comment: Also note that the block inside your map can be simplified to `persons.map(p => (( <div ... </div> ));` since it's technically a single line return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Repeat only the `<li>` inside map because it's List item.
- Use *array index* as **key** as person name can be the same in the
  real scenario.

```js
const Person = () => {
  var persons = ["John", "Ron"];

  return (
  <div>
      <ul>
        {
         persons.map((p,i) => {
           return (<li key={i}> I am {p} </li>)
         })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(<Person />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the resulting array of `map` or `undefined` will be returned from the `Person` component, which React doesn't allow.

```js
const Person = () => {
  var persons = ["John", "Ron"];

  return persons.map(p => (
    <div key={p}>
      <ul>
        <li> I am {p} </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   ));
};

ReactDOM.render(<Person />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: got it! map `returns` and then the component also `returns`

Comment: @Deke Practically the above solution is not completely correct as per me. As to list the People whole structure should not be repeated but only li should be repeated.

As per above code whole structure of the div will be repeated for each person, which according to me is not correct.

Comment: @RonitMukherjee I think Deke knows that and can change that as he see fit. The question was more specifically why the error `Person(...): Nothing was returned from render...` occurred.